# How can I upload my joomla from scratch while keeping everything in place

Tags: php, joomla, installation, backup, virus

my Joomla site has been infected with some virus, I managed to take it out but I'm afraid of that the attacker might have left a backdoor inside my server. I'm willing to take everything out of my site and re-install everything. Is there a way I could do it quickly? How can I save the db and configs?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Joomla Docs has a fairly decent step by step checklist for recovering from hacks: http://docs.joomla.org/Security_Checklist/You_have_been_hacked_or_defaced

Answer (score 1):

To backup the database, go into phpMyAdmin, select the database your Joomla site is running on, then there will be a button to "Export". click that, highlight all the tables and download it.

AS for the config file, you can get that from the root of the Joomla site in the FTP. The file is called **configuration.php**

What you could do, it take a full site backup, using the backup manager in your control panel, if there is one, or zip everything in the FTP and download it. Once done, extract the zip into a newly created folder and scan with an up to date, decent anti virus. If you don't have one, download a trial version of AVG Internet security 2013.